# Is the integral of the squared distance function smooth on a compact Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and let $d$ be the natural distance on it.

> Is the function $$x \mapsto \int _M d(x,y) ^2 \, \mathrm d y$$ smooth?

Had it not been for the integral, the map $x \mapsto d(x,y) ^2$ is smooth outside the cut locus of $y$, for fixed $y$. The problem is the integral, which makes $y$ vary, and I do not know how to investigate this.

If the above function (let us call it $f$) is not smooth, is there any theoretical framework in which I could say that
$$\Delta f = \int _M \Delta_x \, d(x,y)^2 \, \mathrm d y$$
where the lower index $x$ indicates the variable with respect to which the Laplacian acts? And what could be the meaning of the integrand? I have tried placing the problem in the context of distribution theory, but this did not allow me to slip the Laplacian inside the integral, which is what I am after.